# Values not get populated on item level in sap during contract creation

Tags: abap, bapi, sap-erp

I am trying to create contract and update item level data in SAP using bapi extensions(extensionin). The values are getting populated in extensionin internal table but not appearing on va43(in contract display). I am using this BAPI:

```
CALL FUNCTION 'BAPI_CONTRACT_CREATEFROMDATA'
  EXPORTING
    contract_header_in      = ls_contractheaderin
    contract_header_inx     = ls_contractheaderinx
  TABLES
    return                  = lt_return
    contract_items_in       = lt_contractitemsin
    contract_items_inx      = lt_contractitemsinx
    contract_partners       = lt_contractpartners
    contract_data_in        = lt_contract_data_in
    contract_data_inx       = lt_contract_data_inx
    contract_conditions_in  = lt_conditionin
    contract_conditions_inx = lt_conditioninx
    extensionin             = lt_extensionin.
```

The values are getting populated in lt_extensionin but not in contract display even after the bapi commit is used. How to resolve. Answers with explanations are appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: Please check the online documentation of the `extensionin` parameter and double-check whether you made *all* of the adjustments described there. If you're sure you did so, please add images / copies of the extensions here so that we can double-check.

Comment: If you have not been able to create contract there must be some error or lack in the data you send to the bapi. Can you debug the execution of this bapi and see what it is returning in the table variable 'RETURN'? That may give you information about what needs to be done.